# Package not imported in Java

Tags: java

```
import java.text.DateFormatSymbols;

public class GregorianCalendar
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] shortWeekdays = new getShortWeekdays();
        for(String wd : shortWeekdays)
            System.out.printf("%4s", wd);
    }
}
```

Compiler output:

```
GregorianCalendar.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
        String[] shortWeekdays = new getShortWeekdays();
                                     ^
  symbol:   class getShortWeekdays
  location: class GregorianCalendar
1 error
```

I've added `import java.text.DateFormatSymbols;`. Why it's still telling me "cannot find symbol"?

Comment: and where did you **defined** getShortWeekdays() function in GregorianCalendar?

Comment: @Biffen:- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormatSymbols.html#getShortWeekdays()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following ::

```
DateFormatSymbols df = new DateFormatSymbols(  );
String[] shortWeekdays = df.getShortWeekdays( );
```

or,

```
String[] shortWeekdays = new DateFormatSymbols( ).getShortWeekdays( );
```

or even,

```
String[] shortWeekdays = DateFormatSymbols.getInstance( ).getShortWeekdays( );
```

Previously it could not find the function getShortWeekdays(). Because you did not create a new instance of the class DateFormatSymbols.

Comment: I didn't downvote--just got here--but OP was trying to _instantiate the class_ `getShortWeekdays` using a default constructor. It's not that the system couldn't find a function getShortWeekdays(); it couldn't find a _class_ by that name.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
String[] shortWeekdays = DateFormatSymbols.getInstance().getShortWeekdays();
```

GetShortWeekdays() is a method which cannot be instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to instantiate the class `getShortWeekdays()` using the `new` operator. However, you have not defined the class getShortWeekdays(), therefore you ae getting the compiler output you pasted.